# React Native Error - Unable to resolve "./withSafeArea" from "node_modules\react-native-safe-area-view\index.js"

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've just updated my React native version to 0.57 from 0.55.

I'm getting bunch of errors starting from Barbel, fixing errors one by one.

Now I'm encountering

> "Unable to resolve "./withSafeArea" from
>   "node_modules\react-native-safe-area-view\index.js"

Error, and that's all information the console gives. 
I tried googling it, seems like I'm the first one encountering this error.
What is the error here?

So far I've tried:

1. delete node_modules folder and do npm install again.
2. npm install react-native-safe-area-view.

Both no luck :(